# How to set metrics "HLLSketchMerge" in apache superset with druid

Tags: druid, apache-superset

Seems like superset support only closed list of aggregation function, what can I do if I want to use HLL metrics, like HLLSketchMerge?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the data source configuration level.
[image]